# "undefined" error in wdio-cucumber-framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, undefined, webdriver-io

"undefined" error is intermittent, so i am not able to provide you the code to reproduce this error. Sometimes in case of individual test script execution  as well as for test suite execution, this error will occur basically while the page is loading and there is no specific description about this error. I am not able to figure out that why I am getting this error because all of my steps is defined.
The screenshot of this error is below:

[image: screenshot]

running npm version 3.10.3 and node 6.4.0 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

FYI this has been fixed in wdio-cucumber-framework 0.3.1, [see following issue](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2093)

The issue was that Cucumber is reporting timeout errors as a string whereas wdio-cucumber-framework was expecting an error object.

The default step timeout in cucumberOpts is 20s, so if one of your step sometimes takes more than 20s to execute then the test fails, which is the expected behavior. However the error message was not printed correctly, thus leaving us with no clue about what was the cause of the error.

Hope that helps.